# Spring Boot two databases JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two Postgres databases and a SpringBoot application.  I connect to each database and perform separate transactions on each successfully. This has working fine as long as I have been using normal queries on my secondary database.

1. Primary: powwow
2. secondary: pims

As soon as I try execute a native query on the secondary (pims) database, it thinks it is looking at the primary database (powwow).

e.g. This "merchants" table is on the secondary database (pims):

> PSQLException: ERROR: relation "merchants" does not exist

If I run the same native query but over a table on the primary  (powwow) database, it works fine.  So I think there's a problem with my config where I define the secondary  (pims) datasource.

If I run a non native query over the secondary (pims) database using a repository in the `com.xxxx.powwow.entities.pims` package, it works fine.

**Question**

How do I execute a native query using a dao in the `com.xxxx.powwow.dao.pims` package?

**PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.xxxx.powwow.dao.pims", "com.xxxx.powwow.repositories.pims"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "pimsEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "pimsTransactionManager")
public class PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${spring.datasource1.jdbc-url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource1.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String hbm2ddl;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.database-platform}")
    private String platform;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profile;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource1")
    public DataSource pimsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    //@Bean(name = "pimsEntityManager")
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean pimsEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(pimsDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.xxxx.powwow.entities.pims"});
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        String host = null;
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        logger.info("Setting spring.datasource1 (pims): hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto='"+hbm2ddl+"', platform='"+platform+"', url='"+url+"', username='"+username+"', host='"+host+"', profile='"+profile+"'.");
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager pimsTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(pimsEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**BookingHistoryReportDao.java** (package `com.xxxx.powwow.dao.pims`)

```
@Component
@Transactional("pimsTransactionManager")
public class BookingHistoryReportDao {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BookingHistoryReportDao.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void executeBookingHistoryReport(Date startDate, Date endDate, List<Integer> companyIds) {
        final String sql = getSQLBookingHistoryReportDao();
        try {
            Query qry = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
            List<String> merchants = qry.getResultList();
            logger.info("done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error executing query for BookingHistoryReport.", e);
            logger.info(sql);
        }
    }

    private String getSQLBookingHistoryReportDao() {
        return "select company_name from Merchants limit 100";
    }
}
```

Comment: It has to be a native query  without defined entities because the sql I want to eventually execute is a lot  more complex than the one in this example.

Comment: See above, or you can create multi-module project. 1-1 module will be handling the database with Spring, and you have to create some service/interface that you will use in core project. So you have not configured database in core project, just submodules.

Comment: @Numichi thanks for the reply, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I see, u have not used google to answer what is multiple modules in maven/gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by using the `PersistenceUnitName`.

e.g.

set it in the config:

```
em.setPersistenceUnitName("pimsPersistenceUnit");
```

and reference in the DAO:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pimsPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```